# Is there any better way of coding this as it feels very impractical and takes a lot of space

Tags: javascript, typescript, code-cleanup

Is there any better way of coding this as it feels very impractical and takes a lot of space. It is basically a random chance of getting a rarity, for example **Getting a Uncommon sword**.

```
if (Math.random() * 100 < 100 / (19.37 / NewData.PriceDivider)) {
        Rarity = Rarities.uncommon;
        Embed.addField("Rarity", Rarity, true);
        Embed.setColor("GREEN");
      } else if (Math.random() * 100 < 100 / (5.18 / NewData.PriceDivider)) {
        Rarity = Rarities.common;
        Embed.addField("Rarity", Rarity, true);
        Embed.setColor("GREY");
      } else if (Math.random() * 100 < 100) {
        Rarity = Rarities.basic;
        Embed.addField("Rarity", Rarity, true);
        Embed.setColor("GREY");
      }
```

Comment: Please define "better"

Comment: 13 lines isn't "a lot of space".

Comment: @Andy this is just like 5% of this.. there are wayy more rarities

Comment: @LeeTaylor as in taking less space, this is just like 5% of the code, there are way more rarities

Comment: I'd use lookup tables for your percentages, rarities, etc. Use one random number to find the item in your lookup table.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could avoid rewriting the assignment statements by using ternary operator :

```
let rdm = Math.random() * 100
const firstCase = 19.37 / NewData.PriceDivider
const secondCase = 19.37 / 100 / (5.18 / NewData.PriceDivider)

// Handle rdm === 100 here  if (rdm === 100) // do something

Rarity = rdm < firstCase ? Rarities.uncommon : rdm < secondCase ? Rarities.common : Rarities.basic
Embed.addField("Rarity", Rarity, true);
Embed.setColor(rdm < firstCase ? "GREEN" : "GREY");
```

If you want to handle the case where Math.random() === 1, I think you should handle it before this code block.

Comment: That's worse. Nested ternaries are terrible for readability.

Comment: That's pretty subjective, the eslint rule is optional and it depends on your coding style, some programmers used to ternaries read better the concise code if it has a proper indentation. https://medium.com/javascript-scene/nested-ternaries-are-great-361bddd0f340

Comment: what is good/better and more clear here is that only 1 Random is used to select the outcome. the original would be non-deterministic, necessitating code like "Math.random() * 100 < 100" (which is *true*).

Comment: I know what OP's code does. I have no idea what yours does.

Comment: @chovy The fact "you have no idea what a ternary expression does" means probably that you are biased to reason as for `if statements` and not `if expressions`. I understand that, but I don't think it's right to say in an absolutistic way *that's worse* or *that's better*. Read the medium article I linked by Eric Elliot, I think his opinion counts more than mine, I agree with him that we should even cease to call them *nested* ternaries...

Comment: I didn't say I didn't know what a ternary was. I said your code is unreadable because its using nested ternaries.